# Complex Core Data predicate with to-many relations

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, nspredicate

I have 4 entities. ArticleGroup, Article, WarehouseStok, Warehouse.

I need to fetch articleGroups which have articles(NSSet) which belong to warehouseStocks(NSSet) which belong to warehouse(single).

```
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(articles, $a, SUBQUERY($a.warehouseStocks, $y, $y.warehouse == %@))", warehouse];
```

I got this error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "SUBQUERY(articles, $a, SUBQUERY($a.warehouseStocks, $y, $y.warehouse == %@))"'

How do I construct such a predicate? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A SUBQUERY returns a *set* of matching objects. A *predicate* must returns *true* or *false*, for example "SUBQUERY(...).@count > 0".

In your case that would be:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(articles, $a, SUBQUERY($a.warehouseStocks, $y, $y.warehouse == %@).@count > 0).@count > 0", warehouse];
```

But I think that you can simplify your predicate to (untested):

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(articles, $a, ANY $a.warehouseStocks.warehouse == %@).@count > 0", warehouse];
```